# Retrieve posts by author

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to retrieve all custom post types created by the current user.

I have this piece of code:

```
wp_get_current_user();

$args_my_items = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
    'post_author' => $current_user->ID);

query_posts($args_my_items);
```

What ends up being returned are all posts of type "mycustomposttype".  It does not filter by post_author.

Am I using the wrong query parameters? How can I filter by the current user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the `author` parameter as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters). Try to use:

```
$args_my_items = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'mycustomposttype',
    'author' => $current_user->ID
);

query_posts($args_my_items);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.  I looked at the post table and I saw a column labeled 'post_author' so i thought that would work. I wonder why the parameter does not match the table column.